# How to use oracle in cakePHP

Tags: php, oracle, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I use cakephp-2.4.7.

And I get  error following message when I’ try to use oracle.

```
Missing Datasource
Error: Datasource class Oracle could not be found.
```

And I find an article http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html that cakePHP doesn’t support oracle.

Is there any trick what I can  use oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP has stopped supporting Oracle since version 2.x. You should either choose CakePHP 1.3 or some other php framework which supports Oracle.

We can use upper version of cakePHP , just we have to do is to donload oracle parsing file from github and place it in C:\wamp\www\Cakephp\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo

Comment: Could you tell me the source of this information?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html, Oracle is not listed in the datasource list. The only way to do it, is plain php.

Comment: Yes. This is the same page I found too. No listed is enough to understand oracle isn't support now. But do you know there is nothing plans to support Oracle in a near future?

Comment: "You should either choose CakePHP 1.3 or some other php framework which supports Oracle." - A valid opinion but I wouldn't call that an answer. "The only way to do it, is plain php" is, well it's _one_ way - there's always choices. There's no _official_ oracle datasource - that doesn't mean there is no datasource e.g. [this datasource](https://bitbucket.org/odin88/cakephp-2.0-oracle) was very easy to find - there are others too.