# CakePHP 2.5 rawQuery how to loop the results?

Tags: php, cakephp, pdo, cakephp-2.x

Using CakePHP 2.5 `rawQuery`, which is the best way to iterate through the results?

I am using native PHP `oci_execute` then `oci_fetch_array`.

Is there any CakePHP way that can do the same?

```
$results = $db->rawQuery($data_sql);
$search_results = oci_execute($results);
while ( ( $row = oci_fetch_array($search_results, OCI_BOTH ) ) != false)
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `DboSource::rawQuery()` returns a `PDOStatement` object if the query was successful.

You can use the standard methods provided by PHP to deal with `PDOStatement` objects.

This should work:

```
$results = $db->rawQuery($data_sql);
foreach ($results as $row){
    //code inside loop
}
```

For further information, see:

- [The `PDOStatement` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)
- [`DboSource::_execute()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-DboSource.html#__execute)

Comment: Not sure if it works with CakePHP 2.5.2 or maybe i am doing wrong , i try and say :  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: make sure the query is returning results. Please post the output of `var_dump($results)`;

Comment: I run the generated query into sqldeveloper directly and it bring results. In the CakePHP script i debug $results and it says resource, but when reaching the foreach, it says Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Just to make sure, you have called `$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');`, right?

Comment: Here is my code: `$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

$dbSql = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE info = ".base64_decode($info)."";

$dbQuery = $db->rawQuery( $dbSql );

foreach( $dbQuery as $row )
{
    $resultDb['Res']['id'] = $row['id'];
    $resultDb['Res']['name'] = $row['name'];
}`

Comment: Is `base64_decode($info)` a string or a number? If it's a string, you have to wrap it in single quotes. Also note the double `""` that follows.

Comment: I think this happens because i am using Oracle, so it return a resource and not array. To mysql it will work !

Comment: Apparently CakePHP no longer supports Oracle. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506993/how-to-use-oracle-in-cakephp). If your solution using the OCI driver is working, perhaps you should stick to it.